# Why is the tolerance of site so low on bad questions?

Tags: discussion

When I tried to post a new question when I had received two downvotes on my first question it said you can't post another question for several days! I think a few Stack Exchange sites (if any) are like this! Restricting a user just for asking **one** question which isn't received very well? A new user should be given time to get better. This behavior is really killing a new contributor's enthusiasm and motivation! I can't post a question even now! On Math site I got restricted after posting *four* bad questions. On Astronomy, I'm doing well (after learning).

P.S. Before I'm accused of lying, I also have a second asked question. But still low tolerance. Because that was because of that *one* question that I got restricted.

Answer (score 2):

The Low Quality question bans are defined and enforced by the network. The criteria which trigger it are intentionally kept hidden to avoid gaming the system, but as far as I know it's no more restrictive on Islam.SE than it is on any other site on the network.

If you find that you've triggered it, see [this Meta.SE post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/86997/132874) for details and instructions on how to improve your situation and possibly have it dropped. However, if you have issues with how restrictive it is in general, you should probably take them to [Meta.SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com) since there's literally nothing we can do about it here.